# Print a char extracted from a string in mips

Tags: string, char, mips

I'm trying to print the first char from a given string. But no matter what I try, I'm not able to do so.
Here is my code:

```
.data
    string: .asciiz "stringer"
    char: .asciiz "c"

.text
.globl main
    main:   

    li $v0, 4                   # 4 is the print_string syscall.
    la $a0, string              # load the addr of the given string into $a0. 
    syscall

    li,$v0, 11                  # service 11 is print character
    lb  $t1, 0 ($a0)
    syscall

    exit:
    li $v0, 10                # return control to SPIM OS
    syscall
```

Thanks.

Comment: Should be `lb $a0 0($a0)`

Comment: Thanks! And let's say that I want to move to the next char on the string afterwards, what should I add to the code?

Comment: As Konrad pointed, the character you are going to print has to be stored in `$a0`. Since a character has a size of one byte, printing the second character would be `lb $a0, 1($a0)`, the third one `lb $a0, 2($a0)` and so on. You could be interested in having a counter in `$t1` (for example) that gets increased in one unit after printing one character, so you can then access the following one.